# How actually Lenovo's Superfish works in general (step-by-step)?

Tags: tls

There isn`t a clear, step-by-step explanation about Superfish adware here, all questions and answers are kind of specific for different aspects of it, but nothing in general.

So, how Lenovo's Superfish actually works under the hood when it comes to it's MiTM SSL part? How the encryption is bypassed and the authenticity is achieved?

Is there a change in the public key sended with the X.509 certificate modified by Superfish?

Comment: Although Superfish isn't specifically addressed here, there are many discussions about certificate chains and MitM.

Comment: There is also much discussion elsewhere about the potential threat Superfish poses: http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/02/19/superfish-need-to-know/

Comment: https://github.com/0xPoly/Superphish

Comment: and another step-by-step: https://blog.filippo.io/komodia-superfish-ssl-validation-is-broken/

Comment: From errata security: http://blog.erratasec.com/2015/02/exploiting-superfish-certificate.html#.VOjmtIDX9IC